# How to alter ibm mq qm to connect with user and pass

Tags: ibm-mq

İ tried the following command but it did not work.

```
alter authinfo(system.default.authinfo.idpwos) authtype(idpwos) chckclnt(required)
```

Anyone worked on this subject before?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, since my reputation below 15 i could not accept the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make changes to the connauth authinfo objects you need to run `REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)` for the changes to take effect.  A restart of the queue manager would also have the same effect.

This is documented in the [Knowledge Center - Turning on connection authentication on a queue manager](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSFKSJ_8.0.0/com.ibm.mq.sec.doc/q113250_.htm)

> To check local connections, use the AUTHINFO attribute CHCKLOCL (check local connections). To check client connections, use the AUTHINFO attribute CHCKCLNT (check client connections). **The configuration must be refreshed before the queue manager recognizes the changes.**
>
> ```
> ALTER QMGR CONNAUTH(USE.PW)
> DEFINE AUTHINFO(USE.PW) +
> AUTHTYPE(IDPWOS) +
> FAILDLAY(10) +
> CHCKLOCL(OPTIONAL) +
> CHCKCLNT(REQUIRED)
>
> REFRESH SECURITY TYPE(CONNAUTH)
> ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
> ```

I would also suggest that you set the AUTHINFO object parameter ADOPTCTX(YES) as well as set ChlauthEarlyAdopt=E in your qm.ini channels stanza.  See @T.Rob's excellent presentation [`"CONNAUTH Doesn't work like you think it does"`](http://www.slideshare.net/tdotrob/ibm-mq-connauthchlauth-doesnt-work-like-you-think-it-does-and-if-you-arent-careful-may-not-work-at-all) for more details on why.